# order by sum t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select 
    w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, q.userId, 
    SUM(q.bidCount) as sumOfBids
from 
    geopl_kubetiAuct.firstWeekBids as q 
join 
    geopl_kubetiAuct.Users w on q.userId = w.Id
where 
    q.bidedItem = 'laptop' 
group by 
    w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, q.userId
```

This selects all users which meets this requirements. How can I do that it selects top 2 `sumOfBids`?

I've added `order by  sumOfBids top 2 desc` above `group by` but it doesn't works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 2 w.firstName,
             w.lastName,
             w.fbId,
             q.userId,
             Sum(q.bidCount) AS sumOfBids
FROM   geopl_kubetiAuct.firstWeekBids AS q
       INNER JOIN geopl_kubetiAuct.Users w
               ON q.userId = w.Id
WHERE  q.bidedItem = 'laptop'
GROUP  BY w.firstName,
          w.lastName,
          w.fbId,
          q.userId
ORDER  BY sumOfBids DESC
```